# Cocos2d fast collision detection with many sprites

Tags: performance, cocos2d-iphone, collision

I have a LOT of sprites (shooting game) and I need to test collision with many other objects in the level (Player, walls, crates etc...) and it's working fine if I brute force the CGRectIntersectsRect method. The problem is very apparent with this method as I'm checking every bullet against every object every frame. I know a bit about how to speed things up but I wanted to get some more experience game dev's insight (perhaps cocos2d specific) before I spend a couple days implementing some sort of spacial partitioning hierarchy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think we are doing the same method. What I did is I loop in the array of my bullets and inside that loop are another loops for my other sprites array to check the collision of bullets and other sprites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use box2d to detect and process all collisions. It already uses optimizations.

Comment: Will the overhead of box2d really be worthwhile? I'll look into this immediately

Comment: Box2D certainly adds more overhead to simple rectangle tests. If all you need are rect and distance tests, Box2D is overkill and will surely be slower.

Comment: as he mentioned in his post, he has "... a LOT of sprites...". In such way box2d will process them faster.

Answer (score 0):

One optimization that's pretty straightforward is not to test every object with every other object. Because if A tests collision with B, this means that B doesn't have to do collision with A since the result was already obtained.

If you have 200 objects, the brute force approach requires 40,000 tests to test all objects against each other. If you optimize this to skip already performed tests, you can cut down the number of tests to a few thousands because the first object tests the other 199, the second tests the remaining 198 (because the second already tested collision with the first), and so on.

Assuming all your objects are in an array, you iterate over all 200 and inside the loop you iterate over current + 1 to 200.

Comment: this will only cut it down by 1/2